# What is causing Safari to fail at getting navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition in this code?

Tags: php, javascript, ios, mobile, geolocation

**SECOND UPDATE:** With no fix for Safari and a couple other odd behaviors, I decided to create all new boring content for Safari users using this selection (basically giving up on scripting for Safari)...

```
<?php if($detect->version('Safari')) {  ?>
$(function() {
    /* create second option because Safari sucks? */
    $("#gotorep").remove();
    $("#entersite").remove();
    $("#entersite2").css({'display':'inline'});
});
<?php } elseif($detect->isMobile()) {  ?>
   function startfunc() {
      if(navigator.geolocation) {
.
.
.
```

**ERROR UPDATE (*this was fixed, removed*):** my error in Safari is 35772ReferenceError: Can't find variable: fail in this location...

```
 $(function() {
    if(navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
        var fallback = setTimeout(function() { fail('10 seconds expired'); }, 10000);
***http://devv.referadiabetic.com/:35772ReferenceError: Can't find variable: fail
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                function (pos) {
                    clearTimeout(fallback);
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:** I can get this to work in other mobile devices/browsers except Safari. While on the iphone it failed, so reversed the if selection with ! and tested in a Safari desk-top browser with the same issues, not returning my data once I agree. This is the block of code I am working with now...

```
<?php if(!($detect->isMobile())) {  ?>
$(function() {
    if(navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
        var fallback = setTimeout(function() { fail('10 seconds expired'); }, 10000);
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                function (pos) {
                    clearTimeout(fallback);
                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
                    new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({'latLng': point}, function (res, status) {
                        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && typeof res[0] !== 'undefined') {
                            var zip = res[0].formatted_address.match(/,\s\w{2}\s(\d{5})/);
                            if(zip) {
                                var zipcodepassed = zip[1];
                                $("#em").html(zipcodepassed);
                                var reps = reps_load;
                                var ads_repList_URLtoFullName = ads_repList_URLtoFullName_load;
                                var rek = ads_repList_URLtoFullName;
                                var rep = reps[zipcodepassed];
                                    if (rep == undefined || rep == null || rep == "") {
                                            $(function() {
                                                $("#gotorep").remove();
                                                $("#entersite").remove();
                                                $("#entersite2").css({'display':'inline'});
                                            });
                                    }
                                var repname = rek[rep]; //i.e. shaner will be Shane Reaume in repname variable
                                $("#yourrep").html(repname);
                                $("a[href='http://devv.referadiabetic.com']").attr('href', 'http://devv.referadiabetic.com/' + rep);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
        );

    }
});
```

I already have this as a fall back, I am using IP addresses to get zip codes, but because of the nature of mobile devices, I am setting those to perform this block of code.

Comment: It happens on desktop Safari, right?  Pop open the developer tools and watch the console while it's running, you may see errors there.

Comment: @Charles I shared my error at the top and am looking into this now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` expects the first parameter to be a string of some code or a call to a function. I believe that it's trying to parse `fail` as a string, and... erm... failing.

```
setTimeout("function() fail('10 seconds expired');", 10000);
```

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout), you should be able to pass a function directly to setTimeout without a problem.  The code, as you've altered it, will actually just return a function... but it's not really being returned anywhere, so it's basically a no-op.  That doesn't stop `fail` from not being defined in the context of the setTimeout, of course, which is the underlying problem.

Comment: I agree, but Safari definitely has some problem with `fail`. At this time I would usually look to see if it's a reserved word, but I already know it's not.

Comment: @Charles I removed the fallback and now I do not get an error, but it also does not return the location still.